# Best practice for handling an args dictionary: unpack into individual variables or pass dictionary around?

Tags: python, python-2.7, code-cleanup

For example, the following code gets very lengthy. I then have to pass these each into their relevant functions. The benefit here is that I can easily specify defaults all in one place (for me the class `__init__`).

```
### Parse Arguments ###
self.rui_server = self.args.get("Server", "https://url.com")
self.system_name = self.args.get("SystemName", "Generic_Accessor")
self.predicates = self.args.get("Predicates", None)
self.keywords = self.args.get("Keywords", None)
self.number_of_tests = self.args.get("NumberOfTests", None)
self.matching_lookback_count = self.args.get("MatchingLookbackCount", 10)
self.update_period = self.args.get("UpdatePeriod", 3)  # in days 
self.readable_logs_key = self.args.get('ReadableLogsKey', None)
```

VS

```
self.args.setdefault("Server", "https://url.com")
...etc...
```

Then make `self.args` available to every method or subclass. There is no issue with everyone having access to everything else in my implementation.

So what is actually better here and why? Or is there an even better way that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why are you using a dictionary and not a class (e.g. a namedtuple)?

Comment: @DanielPryden correct, args is being returned from a JSON input to a class I have no control over.

Comment: It may be JSON when you receive it, but you can still wrap it into a class before passing it around to the rest of your code.

Comment: Sorry @DanielPryden what I meant was the class that converts the JSON to a dict and passes it to me is what I don't have control over. Or are you saying making another class that's just home to all these arguments is better?